# How to update an entity using @onetomany relationship in JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-onetomany

I created an entity using a tree structure and parent child relations using @ManyToOne and @OneToMany annotations. However only changes I made to a parent of an entity are processed in the database.

My entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class OKR {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private OKR parent;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<OKR> children;
    private boolean isRoot;

    public OKR(String name, OKR parent, List<OKR> children){
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
        if (this.children==null){
            this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.parent = parent;

        if (parent == null||parent.equals(new UUID(0,0))){
            isRoot = true;
        }else{
            isRoot = false;

        }
    }

    protected OKR(){
        isRoot = true;
        children = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

When I update an OKR by changing its parent, the parent OKR is updated as well. However when I update an OKR by only adding a child, the child OKR does not get updated. I'm fairly new to JPA and I also noticed that there is no table for children inside my database. So my question is what is the easiest way to update all relations when only updating the children of an entity?

Comment: Do you have setters and getters for all of your variables in this entity?

Comment: Yes I have, I should have mentioned that I removed them here for simplicity.

Comment: When adding a child, in my view the object you persist should be the child, not the parent. Since it is the one that does not have an ID yet.

Test whether by modifying an existing child and updating the parent, the child is updated and if so the new child should persist with its parent property filled